# What buildings can I leave unprotected without problem?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Are there buildings that I can leave outside my walls, unprotected, without having to worry about them?

Basically, what buildings have the smallest impact when they are destroyed in an attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on if you care about trophies or not.

If you do, then every building is sacred and should be protected.  The more your base is leveled, the more stars the enemy gains, and the more trophies you'll lose.

However, for most players trophies are secondary to resources.  Also, at most of the lower levels, you can't protect every building.  In this case, you generally want to protect anything resource-related (collectors and storage facilities for gold and elixir, primarily) along with any defensive structures like cannons.

In fact, it's actually common to leave your Town Hall outside of your walls - when destroyed, it automatically gives you a free shield that will protect you from further raids for at least a little while.

Whatever you do, don't try to use buildings to plug holes in your walls - enemies that choose targets (like Goblins and Giants) will walk right past them to attack the types of building they prioritize.

Answer (score 1):

Keep everything protected if you have enough walls. Each building counts equally to destruction percentage.

If you don't have enough walls, put Army Camps and Barracks outside unprotected. They act as decoy, too (they would be attacked first protecting other units). So, you can use them smartly around corners. At corner, put a splash damage defense unit like Wizard Tower.